# Search for a word in an answer but not in a title does not exclude the title

Tags: support, search

I wanted to find answers which included the word `NSTokenField`, but whose question did *not* have that term in the title. (I was looking for a "what is this UI element"-type question as a dupe target).

I used this search: [nstokenfield is:answer -title:nstokenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nstokenfield+is:answer+-title:nstokenfield) and ended up with lots of answers to questions with `NSTokenField` in both the title and the answer's body.

[image]

Am I expecting too much from the search? Is there another way to accomplish this effect? This obviously isn't possible with Google, because it doesn't distinguish between title and body, let alone questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `body:NSTokenField` to specify it should specifically appear in the body of a post:

```
body:NSTokenField -title:NSTokenField is:answer isaccepted:yes
```

*I've added `isaccepted:yes` for convenience*

[Results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-title:NSTokenField%20body:NSTokenField%20is:answer%20isaccepted:yes)

Comment: I'm still seeing a few titles with the word, but these are good enough results! Not using `body:` was definitely the oversight I was having.