# How do I search for titles not containing a word

Tags: support, search

I wanted to find C++ questions containing `placement new` in an answer, but not in the title. I tried:

```
[c++] placement new -title:placement
```

This seemed to ignore the `-title:placement` term, as many of the results had `placement` in the title

and

```
[c++] placement new title:-placement
```

This found nothing, although when I scanned through the results of the search without the `title` term, there was at least one result that should have matched.

Comment: Even with the advanced search techniques, you can't mix question *and* answer specific queries. Your question-specific query is: `[c++] title:?` (whatever `?` is) while your answer-specific query is: `"placement new"`. Moreover, negating `title` queries don't seem to work.

Comment: That's the main thing I was looking for, negating the title query. I was trying to find dupes for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091979/what-is-this-syntax-new-this-t so I wanted to find questions that mention placement new, but don't know what it is. While it would be best if it weren't in the title or question, I figured negating the title would get rid of most of the false positives.

Comment: Someone else ended up closing it as a dupe of a question that asks what placement new is used for, which isn't quite the same thing, although close enough.

Comment: There is, of course, always the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Comment: Similar: [Search for a word in an answer but not in a title does not exclude the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168558)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're trying to do, but use the `body` term to search the body, then the `title` term to remove posts with it in the title

```
[c++] -title:placement body:placement
```

[search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+-title%3Aplacement+body%3Aplacement)

The sidebar described this search as:

> results found not containing
> **title:placement**
>
> tagged with
> [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
>
> search options
> **body placement**

[Advanced search documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: I just tried that. One of the results is "Q: keep the track of placement delete against placement new", another is "A: Allocating object to predefined address in c++ without placement new method"

Comment: If you add `is:answer` it at least isn't in any of the titles on the first page