# Searching for title that doesn't contain word doesn't work

Tags: bug, search

[How do I search for titles not containing a word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233709/how-do-i-search-for-titles-not-containing-a-word) claims that `-title:word` should work to search for questions whose title doesn't include the word.

I tried the following search on Stack Overflow:

```
[c] fflush scanf printf hasaccepted:yes -title:stdin
```

Many of the results contained `fflush(stdin)` in the title. These are the ones I was specifically trying to avoid.

I also tried

```
[c] fflush scanf printf hasaccepted:yes -title:"fflush(stdin)"
```

and I tried:

```
[c] fflush scanf printf hasaccepted:yes title:-stdin
```

Why isn't the negated title working?

Comment: I assume because `title:` isn't a tag, term, or phrase. maybe `-"stdin"`?

Comment: @KevinB The advanced search help says "To limit your search to just the title of a question, use title: followed by the search term."

Comment: That will filter out questions that have `stdin` in the body, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Right, it was more of an explanation (or guess) on why it doesn't work on title:. it's not the same as just a plain term or a tag/phrase. That functionality likely isn't applied to title:

Comment: I also tried negating the phrase, i.e. `title:-stdin`. See the linked question whose answer claims that my attempt was supposed to work.